# Using YCbCr with JPEG tiles in MapProxy

Tags: jpg, mapproxy, compression

MapProxy allows some configuration of the image format used: https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/configuration.html#image-format-options

How can I make it use the YCbCr color space for JPEG tiles? Or does it use that by default already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manually inspecting tiles created by MapProxy I found them to be in YCbCr already. I also compressed them manually again and found not significant change in size.

So my conclusion is that MapProxy's handling of JPEG tiles already uses YCbCr.

In fact according to https://yasoob.me/posts/understanding-and-writing-jpeg-decoder-in-python/ the specs say that

> Images encoded with three components are assumed to be RGB data
> encoded as YCbCr unless (...)

which can explain the very confusing information various tools give about the color spaces in use. The YCbCr color space can be used for storage/compression and the image "is" still RGB.

Answer (score 1):

MapProxy has a good documentation at https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/configuration.html#image-format-options and it does not mention an option to set the PHOTOMETRIC interpretation.

I found also nothing about "photometric" from the source code https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy generally or from the file that sets the options
https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy/blob/3a5d3844faa90065c50110edccaa53c34644c998/mapproxy/image/opts.py

I would say that there is no reason to believe that YCbCr is used by default nor that it could be selected by users.

Comment: Actually it seems like YCbCr is used by default. Manually specifying the color space seems to be a TIFF or GDAL thing.